# "failed to load compute presentation" error while using git.NewRemote for listing tag in golang

Tags: runtime-error, taglist, go-git, ls-remote

i am trying to fetch all the tags of a gitlab repo without cloning the code via go-git package. As per go documentation (https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/v5.4.2/_examples/ls-remote/main.go)
i am using git.newRemote to create a new remote for listing of tags purpose. However i am getting error "failed to load compute presentation" and unable to list tags. Am i missing something?